# How to use re.sub() to leave only letters a-z, A-Z, numbers 0-9 and spaces but not divide numbers?

Tags: python, regex

```
message = 'Hello(/ how{can} wan\';t //opperate+32.5 u&# kj|'
```

I need to leave only letters a-z, A-Z, numbers 0-9 and spaces, so I must get `'Hello how can wan t opperate 325 u kj'` but when I use `re.sub('[^\w\d]+', ' ', message)` or `re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', message)` I get `'Hello how can wan t opperate 32 5 u kj'`
How can I get 325 as a number?

Comment: I think you can use `re.sub(r'(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)+)|[\W_]+', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else ' ', message).strip()`, see https://ideone.com/JrPtRa

Comment: It's probably clearer to use two regexes in that case; one to replace anything not matching a word or a number between two numbers with nothing, then the regex you have to do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)+)|[\W_]+', lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else ' ', message).strip()
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/JrPtRa).

*Details*:

- `(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits followed with one or more occurrences of a `.` or `,` and one or more digits
- `|` - or
- `[\W_]+` - any one or more non-alphanumeric chars.

If Group 1 matches, the replacement is Group 1 value, else, the replacement is a space. If there is a match at the start/end of the string, there may be a stray space left, hence, using `strip()`.

Comment: Thank you, `re.sub(r'(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)+)|[\W_]+', lambda x: re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', x.group(1)) if x.group(1) else ' ', message).strip()` is solution for me.